# Equating eigenvalues of Hermitian matrix and correlating symmetric/antisymmetric matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $AH$ which is created by adding $AS$ and $i*AA$, which are the symmetric and antisymmetric components of the real matrix $A$

So

$AS=(A+A')/2$

$AA=(A-A')/2$

$AH=AS+i*AA$

AH has eigenvectors $E=\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ and eigenvalues $V=\{v_1,v_2,...\}$

How do I find an equation that links together the real part of an eigenvector, the corresponding eigenvalue, and the matrices $AS$ and $AA$?

This is what I have done so far:

$$(AS+i*AA) * e_1 = v_1 * e_1$$

$$(AS+i*AA) * (e_1r+i*e_1c) = v_1 * (e_1r+i*e_1c)$$

Where $e_1r$ is the real component of $e_1$ and $e_1c$ is the imaginary component of $e_1$

$$AS*e_1r + AS*i*e_1c + AA*i*e_1r - AA*e_1c = v_1*e_1r + v_1*i*e_1c$$

using distributive property

This gives me two equations by separating it out into reals and imaginaries

$$AS*e_1r - AA*e_1c = v_1*e_1r$$

$$AS*e_1c + AA*e_1r = v_1*e_1c$$

But my problem is that I'm not sure how to remove $e_1c$ from the top equation and remove $e_1r$ from the bottom. I need the equations just in terms of $v_1$, $AA$, $AS$, and either $e_1r$ or $e_1c$.

Comment: Please use `$` to delimit formulas rather than `\``.

Comment: Is $A$ a real matrix?

Comment: Yes $A$ is real